# how to register separate callback function for each UART port in stm32

Tags: callback, stm32, uart, freertos

I am using Freertos to program in STM32. is it possible to register separate callback function for each UART port in stm32? Whenever data received in that port that particular callback function has to be invoked after receiving data...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()` function, you can act differently depending upon the UART peripheral.

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
  if (huart->Instance == USART1) {
    // USART1
  } else if (huart->Instance == USART2) {
    // USART2
  } else if (huart->Instance == USART3) {
    // USART3
  } else if (huart->Instance == UART4) {
    // UART4
  }
}
```

Same is possible with `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are using HAL, there are a host of functions for differnt callbacks,

```
void HAL_UART_IRQHandler(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_TxHalfCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_RxHalfCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_AbortCpltCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_AbortTransmitCpltCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_UART_AbortReceiveCpltCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
```

You have to pass the UART_HandleTypeDef instance which specifies the UART instance you are trying to use.

Comment: Yes @ched I am using HAL only and I need HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback function only...And ...I meant separate HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback function individually for each UART ports like HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback1() for uart1, HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback2() for uart2 and  HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback3() for uart3...Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. The UART_HandleTypeDef allows you to specify which UART  instance you want to use.